# Average elapsed days between two dates at customer level

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on a way to average elapsed days between two dates on a customer level in SQL Server.

```
SELECT
CUSTOMER,
VISIT_ID,
DAYIN_DATE,
DAYOUT_DATE,
RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER ORDER BY VISIT_ID DESC) AS RANKING,
LAG(DAYOUT_DATE, 1)
OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER ORDER BY VISIT_ID DESC) AS DATEOUT_DT,
LEAD(DAYIN_DATE, 1)
OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER ORDER BY VISIT_ID DESC) AS DATEIN_DT,
(DATEIN_DT - DATEOUT_DT) AS LATENCY
FROM VISIT_TABLE
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4;
```

This code takes the customer and visit(unique id), then ranks them by the DAYIN_DATE/DAYOUT_DATE. I've written a Lag and Lead function to help calculate the latency but, when averaged it doesn't average on a customer level.

What am I missing?

Results:

```
CUSTOMER   VISIT_ID    CHECKIN_DATE    CHECKOUT_DATE   RANKING CHECKIN_DT  CHECKOUT_DT LATENCY
999999999   1111111111  4/27/2015   4/28/2015   1   8/20/2014   (null)  (null)
999999999   2222222222  8/20/2014   8/21/2014   2   8/19/2014   4/28/2015   252
999999999   3333333333  8/19/2014   8/20/2014   3   8/18/2014   8/21/2014   3
999999999   4444444444  8/18/2014   8/19/2014   4   8/17/2014   8/20/2014   3
999999999   5555555555  8/17/2014   8/18/2014   5   7/4/2014    8/19/2014   46
999999999   6666666666  7/4/2014    7/6/2014    6   4/15/2014   8/18/2014   125
```

Desired Results:

```
CUSTOMER_ID    AVGLATENCY_PER_CUST
999999999   17
888888888   12
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify how the table is set up so based on you attempt I believe the table has CUSTOMER, VISIT_ID, DATEIN_DT, DATEOUT_DT.

If the DATEIN_DT and DATEOUT_DT are dates you can use the average and datediff function then group by client.

Example:

```
   SELECT 
     CLIENT,
     AVG(DATEDIFF(dd,DATEIN_DT,DATEOUT_DT)) AverageVisitTime
   FROM VISIT_TABLE
   GROUP BY CLIENT
```